# Change sign of all values in a two-dimensional array for the specific dimension

Tags: c#, arrays

How to change sign of all numbers in a two-dimensional array for the specific dimension ?

I have for example `object[,]` that is filled with value, like

```
[0,1]
[0,2]
[0,3]
```

I want to change the sign for all the values in the second dimension to get

```
[0,-1]
[0,-2]
[0,-3]
```

What is the way to do this efficiently with small amount of code?

I started to think `foreach` for each item but I'm lost already here

```
object[,] values = new object[1, 100];
foreach (object[,] v in values )
    {

    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using an array of objects instead of an array of ints?

Comment: There is in my case. I don't know beforehand what data type is filled to array

Comment: well then, the first option in my answer is, as I wrote, one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
object[,] values = new object[1,10];

for (var i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0);i++) 
{
    for (var j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        var obj = values[i, j];
        int intVal;
        if (obj != null && int.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out intVal))
        {
            values[i, j] = -1 * intVal;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you would use an array of ints, your code would look like this:

```
int[,] values = new int[1, 10];

for (var i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
            values[i, j] = -1 * values[i, j];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with the first suggestion but int.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out intVal) is not succesfull. My obj test value was -4166.666 (I am not necessarily having int values in the array)

Comment: Well, the sample data you provided contained int values only, so... If you are likely to encounter floating points numbers then double.TryParse is a better option then int.TryParse indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 2-Dimensional object array `object[,]` a requirement, or can you represent your data in an easier to work with `int[][]` structure? Something like:

```
int[][] matrix = new[]
{
    new[] {0, 1, 2},
    new[] {0, 2, 4},
    new[] {0, 3, 9}
};
```

Then you can create your desired transform like this:

```
int columnToFlip = 1;
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> flipped = matrix.Select(row => row.Select((value, index) => index == columnToFlip ? -value : value));
```

Or, if you need the result in an `int[][]` array, then:

```
int[][] flippedMatrix = matrix.Select(row => row.Select((value, index) => index == columnToFlip  ? -value : value).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

C# [Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and [Enumerable Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx) are powerful tools for transforming, filtering, ordering, joining, aggregating, grouping, and projecting data.